# Infinitely many primes of the form $\underbrace{11\dots 1}_{k \text{ times}}\dots \underbrace{11\dots 1}_{k \text{ times}}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-progressions

> [Analytic Number Theory - Florian Luca and Jean Marie De Koninck, chapter 14, question 14.9]
>
> Prove that for each positive integer $k$, there are infinitely many primes which when written in base $10$ look like
> $$\underbrace{11\dots 1}_{k \text{ times}}\dots \underbrace{11\dots 1}_{k \text{ times}}$$
> where there are some unspecified digits in the middle.

I am sure that we need to construct a clever arithmetic progression and somehow use Dirichlet's Theorem. But, I can't figure out how.

---

[This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/60825/943723) shows that there are infinitely many digits starting with a given string, and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1892402/943723) shows that there are infinitely many ending in $k$ $1$'s.

Comment: The same question ending with $k$ digits $1$ see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1892399/prove-that-there-are-infinitely-many-prime-numbers-ending-in-k-1s). It works with Dirichlet's theorem.

Comment: Can you use the [prime number theorem for arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Prime_number_theorem_for_arithmetic_progressions)? I think that should enable an argument similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/61538/473276).

Comment: @DietrichBurde I was familiar with the kind of argument used in the link - the problem in my post is that it has to both start and end with a given string of digits

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen again, the link shows that there are infinitely many primes that start with a given string of digits. The question at hand is whether they can both start and end with a given string of digits. I am allowed to use the prime number theorem for arithmetic progressions btw.

Comment: Yes, I said "similar to", not exactly that argument. Apply the PNT for APs to the AP $111\dots1 + 10^k \cdot n$, and then replicate the argument in the answer I linked (basically the post I linked is the same question after you replace $\Bbb N$ with "the set of numbers ending in $11\dots1$", and the PNT for APs says you can do that)

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen I'm sorry, I still don't quite understand the argument. I tried to use your linked post to construct the interval $\left [x,\left(1+\frac 1{10^k}\right)x\right]$ for $x=11\dots 1\times 10^L$ for $L$ sufficiently large. But, it's not like all elements of that interval are of the desired form. Also, now that I checked your wiki link, maybe I am not allowed to use what you suggested. All I can use is that $$\sum_{p\le x\\p\equiv h\pmod k} \frac{\log p}p=\frac{\log x}{\phi(k)}+\mathcal O(1)$$. But, I am aware of the corollary of PNT mentioned in that answer.

Comment: My suggestion was to prove the lemma "let $a, d \in \Bbb N$ be coprime. Then for every $\alpha > 1$, there is some $x_0$ such that for $x > x_0$, there is a prime of the form $a + nd$ in the interval $[x, x \alpha]$". Then apply this for $a = 11\dots1$, $d = 10^k$, $\alpha = 1 + 10^{-k}$ to conclude. However it looks like the form of PNT-for-APs you give might be too weak to prove this lemma. At least I can't see how to prove it from that! (If the remainder was $o(1)$ it would work!). So perhaps you should prove the full version (similar to normal PNT), or maybe there's another proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To elaborate a little on the comments: Let
$$a = \underbrace{11\cdots 1}_{k \text{ times}}$$
and
$$d = 1\underbrace{0\cdots 0}_{k \text{ times}}.$$
Then, by Dirichlet's theorem, there are infinitely many primes of the form $a + nd$ which then have the desired trailing ones.  To get the initial ones, let
$$x = a * 10^n = \underbrace{11\cdots 1}_{k \text{ times}}\;\;\underbrace{00\cdots 0}_{n \text{ times}}$$
for some large $n$ to be decided. Set $c = 1 + 10^{-k}$; then any $y$ with $x \leq y < cx$ must start with $k$ $1$'s as well.  Letting $\pi_{d,a}(x)$ be the number of primes $p \leq x$ of the form $a + nd$, our goal is to show that
$$\pi_{d,a}(cx) - \pi_{d,a}(x) \geq 1.\tag{*}\label{*} $$ Then there is one prime of the desired form. And by varying $n$, we will get infinitely many.

To show $(*)$, we use the prime number theorem for arithmetic progressions, which states that for any given $\epsilon$ and all sufficiently large $x$,

$$(1- \epsilon) \frac {L(x)}{\varphi (d)} < \pi_{d,a}(x) < (1+ \epsilon) {\frac {L(x)}{\varphi (d)}}.$$

where $L(x) = x / \log(x)$. Hence $$\pi_{d,a}(cx) - \pi_{d,a}(x) > \frac{L(cx) - L(x)}{\phi(d)} - 2 \epsilon \frac{L(cx)}{\varphi(d)}$$

and so we are done if we can show that for some $\epsilon$ depending only on $k$ and $d$, that for all sufficiently large $x$  $L(cx) - L(x) > \varphi(d) + 2 \epsilon L(cx)$.

Comment: I kind of get the idea - but still, how do you plan to show $L(cx) - L(x) > \varphi(d) + 2 \epsilon L(cx)$ for sufficiently large $x$?

Comment: Well, at that point it's not number theory anymore and it's some $\epsilon-\delta$ style manipulations.  Give it a shot.

Comment: @SayanDutta, that's just pure real analysis. I would divide both sides by $L(cx)$! +1 btw Jair. This might be the first arithmetic progression I've seen with common difference $a$ and first term $d$ :-)

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Thanks, I always try to innovate ;) I will fix.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen, JairTaylor : I see, it's not as difficult as it seemed (+1)